# ¿Cómo ingresar datos a un arreglo de objetos mediante una función?

Tags: java, poo, array, objeto

Quiero ingresar un número aleatorio generado por una función a un arreglo de objetos, el problema es que al querer ingresarlo me manda un error, aquí el código:
(tengo una clase llamada "Procesos" donde están los métodos getters y setters)

```
package roundrobin;

/**
 *
 * @author george
 */
public class RoundRobin {

    public static int numale() {
        int numale = 0;
        numale = (int) (Math.random() * (25 - 4 + 1) + 4); //Numeros aleatorios desde 4 hasta 25
        return numale;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Procesos pro[] = new Procesos[15];

        pro[0].settempllegada(numale());  //linea 19

        System.out.println(pro[0].getllegada());

    }

}
```

Y esto es lo que me sale cuando ejecuto:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at roundrobin.RoundRobin.main(RoundRobin.java:19)
>       /home/george/.cache/netbeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>       BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: Pero el error dice que no logra compilar. Verifica todas tus clases para corroborar que no esta mal en alguna otra parte

Comment: esto: Procesos pro[] = new Procesos[15]; inicializa cada objeto dentro de la matriz, o queda todo en null?

Comment: Al escribir `pro[0].` estas intentando agarrar "algo" que aún no existe (El arreglo está vacio, por eso el error `java.lang.NullPointerException`)

Comment: @gbianchi Si, yo creo que queda todo en `null` el problema puede estar en el constructor.

Comment: puedes mostrar la clase proceso?

Answer (score 1):

Esto

```
Procesos pro[] = new Procesos[15];
```

crea un array de 15 elementos null. Tienes que hacer un bucle para inicializarlo

```
for (int i=0;i<pro.length;i++) {
   pro[i] = new Procesos(...);
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Primero que nada agradezco tu tiempo para ayudarme, dicho eso, te comento que ya tengo inici-alizados los elementos del arreglo en otra clase

Comment: Hola.
Tu código no refleja eso. Estás declarando un array pro e inmediamente detrás, sin inicializar, lo usas. Si en otra clase tienes declarado e inicialzado otro array pro, no tiene nada que ver con este. Aunque las variables se llamen igual, no están declaradas en el mismo entorno y no tienen nada que ver la una con la otra.
Si quieres "reutilizar" esa varable pro ya inicializada en otra clase, tienes que pasársela de alguna forma a esta clase (un método setPro(), en el constructor,....) en vez de volver a declararla.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya resolví el problema, gracias a todos por su tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

tienes que inicializar el objeto en esa posicion para poderle setear la entrada

```
pro[0] = new Proceso();
pro[0].setLLegada(numale());
```

Comment: Ya comprendí, gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score -1):

class Ejemplo{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Procesos pro[] = new Procesos[15];
    pro[0] = new Procesos(); //te falta este paso el cual tienes que hacer con las 15 posiciones
    pro[0].settempllegada(numale());  
    System.out.println(pro[0].getllegada());
}
```

}

class Ejemplo{

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    Procesos pro[] = new Procesos[15];

    for (int i = 0; i< pro.length;i++) {
      pro[i] = new Procesos();
      pro[i].settempllegada(numale());
    }

  //ya con esto queda instanceado todo tu array.
}
```

}